# Bracket in regexp and as string (elisp)

Tags: regex, string, emacs, elisp

I am creating a bracket/parenthesis completer function, much like packages like auto-pair.

I have the combinations stored in `alist` like: `("[" . "]")`.

When I try to use the `(car (car my-alist))` as a regexp, in `(looking-back REGEXP)`, 
this does not work because it sees this as `"["`, which, instead of a string, is an incomplete regexp:

`looking-back: Invalid regexp: "Unmatched [ or [^"`

How do I use this so that it will still be possible to insert it as a string from `(car (car my-alist))` (so "["), while also being able to use "[" as a regexp?

Note that this does work for `"("`, since this is not a special regexp character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(looking-back (regexp-quote (caar my-alist)))`.

`regexp-quote` is a built-in function in C source code.

```
(regexp-quote STRING)
```

Return a regexp string which matches exactly STRING and nothing else.

Comment: This answers my question, thank you. Will accept as answer when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question...

You should probably consider looking at how the [`paren` library](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/paren.el?h=trunk) is implemented, specifically that it is implemented using the open/close parenthesis classes of the [syntax table](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html).

By doing so, you'd be able to leverage all the built-in functions that [navigate s-expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Motion.html#List-Motion) - and that properly handle nested matching pairs.

Leveraging this built-in functionality will make your code a lot simpler, and will be able to work independent of the mode (i.e. not be restricted to just `[` and `]`).

Comment: Yea, indeed, once I get this basic functionality done, that kind of "counting-to-see-if-we-should-close" would really be something I'd be after. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Dualinity The point is, if you use the syntax table and supporting functions, then you don't need to do any of the "counting-to-see-if-we-should-close"...